# Why is it bad to use Pod IPs to communicate within a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

So I'm setting up a NATS cluster at work in OpenShift. I can easily get things to work by having each NATS server instance broadcast its Pod IP to the cluster. The guy I talked to at work strongly advised against using the Pod IP and suggested using the Pod name. In the email, he said something about if a pod restarted. But like I tried deleting the pod and the new Pod IP was in the list of connect urls for NATS and it worked fine. I know Kubernetes has DNS and you can use the headless service but it seems somewhat flaky to me. The Pod IP works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "the guy at work" has a point, to a certain extent, but it's hard to tell to which extent it's cargo-culting and what is half knowledge. The point being: the pod IPs are not stable, that is, every time a pod gets re-launched (on the same node or somewhere else, doesn't matter) it will get a new IP from the pod CIDR-range assigned.

Now, services provide stability by introducing a virtual IP (VIP): this acts as a cluster-internal mini-load balancer sitting in front of pods and yes, the recommended way to talk to pods, in the general case, is via services. Otherwise, you'd need to keep track of the pod IPs out-of-band, no bueno.

Bottom-line: if NATS manages that for you, keeps track and maps pod IPs then fine, use it, no harm done.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The guy at work is someone who's part of one of the teams to move our current infrastructure to the cloud. His exact words were "Instead of IP, try using the pod name. The IP is dynamic, so if the pod is relaunched it will get a new IP. The pod will be able to resolve itself, but only other pods through a service IP."

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from Michael is mostly true, it is important to understand there is no 100% guarantee that a service IP (aka ClusterIP) service will not change it's IP. There is a specific case of service recreation (delete/create) that will cause service IP change.

That said, the situation is somewhat different for services that have their own means of autodiscovery and/or clustering. Usually it will not be fine or enough to have a single regular service. They need to connect to seed, or discover all nodes etc. One of the means that you might use here are headless services, which return, under given name a full list of all, direct pod IPs.

Mind that using headles service has its tiny quirks as well, ie. not all software re-resolves DNS over time after initial startup, so you might end up with cached endpoints that become obsolete over time.

You might also want to leverage StatefulSets capability to retain a deterministic name (aka network identity) for each pod (ie. mypod-1, mypod-2 etc.) which, combined with headless Service, will give you static per pod names to use.

I do think that using only pod IPs will probably lead to some issues at one edge case or another, so you should at least use one of the above solutions for cluster discovery/registration. For actual communication during and after the pod was registered in the cluster, use of pod IPs can actually be for the best.

Comment: Thanks Radek. The way a cluster is started manually is with one server being the seed and then you have other instances connect to the seed.

I tried StatefulSets combined with Headless Service and I'm pretty certain there's something wrong with the DNS because I set the reconnect count to 5000, went on a lunch break, came back, and pod 0 was still trying to connect to the last pod. What are these edge cases you're talking about?

Comment: what dns name did you use to connect to the seed node ?